# Add limited column to table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have this table that select data from mysql and it works fine. But I would like a 5th column with the prizes for 1st, 2nd and 3rd place, so it should say 'Prize' in the head and then an amount I choose by my self in the first 3 rows and that's it. How can I do that?

```
echo '<tr>

<td><strong>#</strong></td>

<td><strong>Navn</strong></td>

<td><strong>Kampe</strong></td>

<td><strong>Point</strong></td>

</tr>';



$no = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $amount = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
    echo '<tr>
              <td><strong>'.$no.'</strong></td>
              <td>'.$row['Navn'].'</td>

              <td>'.$row['kampe'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['Point'].'</td>

         </tr>';
    $no++;
}
?>
```

I can make the column, but how do I limit it to the first 3 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<tr>

<td><strong>#</strong></td>

<td><strong>Navn</strong></td>

<td><strong>Kampe</strong></td>

<td><strong>Point</strong></td>

<td><strong>Prize</strong></td>

</tr>';


$prizes = array(
1 => 1000,
2 => 750,
3 => 500
);
$no = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $amount = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
    echo '<tr>
              <td><strong>'.$no.'</strong></td>
              <td>'.$row['Navn'].'</td>

              <td>'.$row['kampe'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['Point'].'</td>
              <td>'.(!empty($prizes[$no]) ? $prizes[$no] : '').'</td>
         </tr>';
    $no++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add your fifth column and switch cases with an if

```
echo '<tr>

<td><strong>#</strong></td>

<td><strong>Navn</strong></td>

<td><strong>Kampe</strong></td>

<td><strong>Point</strong></td>

<td><strong>Prize</strong></td>

</tr>';

$no = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$amount = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
// Computing prize
$prize = "";
if($no==1){
   $prize = "1000 €";
} else if($no==2){
   $prize = "500 €";
} else if($no==3){
   $prize = "100 €";
}
echo '<tr>
<td><strong>'.$no.'</strong></td>
<td>'.$row['Navn'].'</td>

<td>'.$row['kampe'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['Point'].'</td>

<td>'.$prize.'</td>

</tr>';
$no++;
}?>
```

Comment: You seems to don't respond to his answer : `how do I limit it to the first 3 rows?`

Comment: He didn't ask to limit the table. Only limit the last column to the 3 first rows

Comment: My bad. I will delete my post